# How to remove underlines for editable cells in Bootstrap-table? X-editable formatting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table, x-editable

I am creating a web page with a central table (**Bootstrap-table**) and some of its columns are editable thanks to **X-editable** and the **Bootstrap-table-editable** extension.

My only problem is that I cannot change the way they are displayed: as blue links, with dotted underlines.

X-editable is highly configurable, and I can customize CSS classes `emptyclass`, `inputclass` and `unsavedclass` - which correspond to an empty value, the inline editor & an unsaved value - but there seems to be no dedicated parameter that would apply to cells in the "un-edited", default, original state...?

I cannot simply add `<span style="text-decoration: none !important; text-underline: none !important; border: none !important;">`, because table rows are created on the fly by Bootstrap-table from JSON data...

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to provide some code. It's not clear what elements you want to style. In [the demo](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) all the underlines are on anchors. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Just override the selector(s) that applies that style. If you inspect the markup that's generated you'll see that  `.editable-click, a.editable-click, a.editable-click:hover` apply a bottom border.  Create your own stylesheet.  Place it after the stylesheet for the plugin and use the cascade of CSS to override these selectors with whatever styles you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @jme11 , adding the following before `</head>` fixes my issue. Thanks!

```
<style>
    a.editable-click { border-bottom: none !important; }
</style>
```